# Show an healthbar on a 10 led display

Tags: c, arduino, binary

For a programming course I have to make a little game with a fubarino and a 10 led display. At one point in the game I need to show the players 'healthbar' or points. The health can be between 10 and 0. I used this bit of code for that.

```
  value = -1;
//set 1 bit off per point lost
  for(int i = 10; i>points[playerNr]; i--){
    value &= !(1<<(points[playerNr]-1));
  }
  showValue(value);
```

the method showValue(int value) is not the problem, that already works for other uses. It shows the bits that are 1 in an integer on then led bar.

My problem is, is that this bit of code flips all the leds of. So I think it sets the value to 0.

I'll add the rest of the method below. But I don't think the problem lies there.

```
// playerNr is either 0 or 1 for one player or 2 for both
void showPoints(int playerNr){
  bool both = false;
  //subtract one point from both players if playerNr == 2
  if(playerNr == 2){
    both = true;
    playerNr = 1;
  }
  points[playerNr]--;
  value = -1;
  //flash all lights to show that the points are going to be shown
  showValue(value);
  delay(50);
  //set 1 bit off per point lost
  for(int i = 10; i>points[playerNr]; i--){
    value &= !(1<<(points[playerNr]-1));
  }
  showValue(value);
  //game position is either 0 or 9
  pos = 9*playerNr;
  //ascend is true if playerNr is 0 and vice versa
  ascend = !playerNr;
  if(both){
    pointLost = 0;
  } else {
    pointLost = -1;
  }
  //reset the game if points are 0
  if(points[playerNr]==0){
    points[0] = 10;
    points[1] = 10;
    points[playerNr]++;
    pointLost = playerNr;
  }
  timer = 1000;
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping to clear bits, you can directly create an integer that has "the n lowest bits set" using `(1u << n) - 1`. This works for all values of `n` in the range 0 to 31 (inclusive). For instance if `n = 3`, this will compute `(1u << 3) - 1`, i.e. `8 - 1` or 7, which in binary is indeed `111`.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on that, your comment is not very clear to me. How would (1u<<n)-1 work, and what value would 'u' take?

Comment: `u` stands for `unsigned` on literals

Comment: @Typhaon That's not a variable, that's an unsigned suffix to make the `1` have type `unsigned int` rather than `int`. And you can replace your entire `for` loop with `showValue((1u << points[playerNr]) - 1);`, that's the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: So 
value = 0;
value |= (1 << points[playerNr]) - 1;

Because only the lowest 10 bits of value are used, it doesnt matter if it's unsigned or not
Got it, thanks!